# OnCompleteListener get results in another class

Tags: android, listener, mvp

I have a `MyActivity` that consists of `FragmentA` and `FragmentB` and `MyActivityPresenter`.
FragmentA:

```
@OnClick(R.id.proceed_sign_up)
public void onBtnProceedSignUp(){
    if(checkInputSignUp()){         
        int returnCode = presenter.createAccount(email, pswd, nick);
        //handle return code: show error on EditTexts,etc.
    }
}
```

Presenter:

```
public int createAccount(String email, String password, final String nickname) {
    final int[] code = new int[1];
    activity.showLoading(true);
    firebaseUserService.createUserWithEmail(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                processLogin(task.getResult().getUser(),                   task.getResult().getUser().getProviderData().get(1), nickname);
            } else {
                Log.d("Create not success", task.getException().toString());
                switch (task.getException().getMessage()) {
                    case "The email address is already in use by another account":
                        code[0] = 10;
                        break;
                    default:
                        code[0] = 20;
                        break;
                }
            }
            activity.showLoading(false);
            activity.showLoginFail();
        }
    });
    return code[0];
}
```

Because operations are asynchronous, `Task<AuthResult>` is not complete when I try to get returnCode from method `createAccount()` in `Fragment` ( so I always get 0). What is the best approach to get value after the task is finished or maybe reorgansze code in some way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to call a method in your View as you're already doing when calling the showLoading and hideLoading methods:

```
 public void createAccount(String email, String password, final String nickname) {
    final int[] code = new int[1];
    activity.showLoading(true);
    firebaseUserService.createUserWithEmail(email, password)
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
          @Override
          public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
              processLogin(task.getResult().getUser(),
                  task.getResult().getUser().getProviderData().get(1), nickname);
            } else {
              Log.d("Create not success", task.getException().toString());
              switch (task.getException().getMessage()) {
                case "The email address is already in use by another account":
                  code[0] = 10;
                  break;
                default:
                  code[0] = 20;
                  break;
              }
              activity.showResult(code[0]);
            }
            activity.showLoading(false);
            activity.showLoginFail();
          }
        });
  }
```

and in the interface your activity implement you add:

```
void showResult(int resultCode);
```

Finally, in the activity/fragment where you implement the interface you'll need to override:

```
@Override
public void showResult(int resultCode){
//do something with resultCode
}
```